# Boost search results according to weight

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I am very new at elasticsearch so am having a hard time to figure this out.

So the thing is I am trying to search content having tags, and these tags will have weights, which will be like,

```
{
  tag: "tag name",
  weight: 1
}
```

right now I am trying this query

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "multi_match": {
            "query": "do",
            "fields": [
              "name",
              "tags.tag"
            ],
            "type": "phrase_prefix"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

But I don't know how to modify the search such that, the search results give the tag weight priorty.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if I understood you question correctly... do you want get the tag weight and affect search result score with it? If yes, please take a look at [script score](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-function-score-query.html#function-script-score). According to documentation you can do something like this:

```
{
  "query": {
    "function_score": {
      "query": {
        "match": { "message": "elasticsearch" }
      },
      "script_score" : {
        "script" : {
          "source": "Math.log(2 + doc['likes'].value)"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```